# CSS: Change Border Color of the table header

Tags: html, css

Just wanted to ask how can I change the border color of the outer portion of table head. Those border between table head should remain white in color. I've done several changes but it seems the default gray did not change. Here is my code:

```css
.table th {
  background-color: #3886BE;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive" id="query_result" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">

  <form>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>S.O.</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Service Avail</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Received</th>
        <th>Completion</th>
        <th>Remaining</th>
        <th>Timeline</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

You may check the image below for reference. I leave some caption there for additional details.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K61SH.png)

Comment: if it is about border, is there anything wrong about using `tr {border:solid #3886BE;}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go Buddy :)

```css
.table th {
  background-color: #3886BE;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th {
    border: 1px solid #3886BE !important;
border-left: 1px solid #fff !important;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff !important;
}
.table-bordered {
    border: 0 !important;
}
table.table.table-bordered.table-responsive {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive" id="query_result" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">

  <form>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>S.O.</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```